# Question about Dini number (hint)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $b$ be a continuous function defined on $[a,b]$. Suppose that there are $u,v \in \mathbb{R}$ such that the Dini number $D^{+}f$ satisfies $u \leq D^{+}f(x) \leq v$ for any $x \in [a,b]$. Show that
>   $$uh \leq f(x+h)-f(x) \leq vh$$
>   for any $a \leq x < x+h \leq b$.

By definition

$$D^{+}f(x) = \limsup_{h \to 0+}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}.$$

So,

$$u \leq \limsup_{h \to 0+}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \leq v.$$

I cannot develop any more. I'm probably not realizing some simple detail, since I'm not seeing where to apply the continuity of $f$. Could someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, the answer is involved so I will give somewhat more than a hint but leave some work for you to do.

If $f$ were differentiable (all Dini derivatives equal) then this would follow easily from the mean value theorem (MVT) since there would exist $c \in (x , x+h)$ such that

$$\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = f'(c)$$

and $u \leqslant f'(c) \leqslant v$ for all $c \in (a,b)$.

Working only with $D^+f$ we use a generalization of MVT by taking for $x \leqslant y \leqslant x+h$,

$$\phi(y) = f(y) - f(x) - \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}(y-x)$$

The continuity of $f$ implies the continuity of $\phi$ and, in addition, we have $\phi(x) = \phi(x+h)=0$. Ignoring the trivial case where  $\phi$ is identically equal to $0$, there must be a point $c \in (x,x+h)$ where $\phi$ has a maximum or minimum. If it is a maximum or minimum, then we can use a well-known result that $D^+\phi(c) \leqslant 0$ or $D^+\phi(c) \geqslant 0$, respectively. This is proved in the solution to Exercise 21.6 in *A Primer of Real Functions* by Boas.

We also need the fact that

$$D^+\phi(y) = D^+f(y) - \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

It is not generally true that $D^+(f +g) = D^+f + D^+g$, but it is true if $g'$ exists -- which is the case here.

Thus, if $\phi$ has a maximum at $c$ we have

$$D^+\phi(c) = D^+f(c) - \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} \leqslant 0,$$

which implies that

$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \geqslant D^+f(c) \geqslant u,$$

giving us one side of the desired inequality.  If there is also a point $c' \in(x,x+h)$ where $\phi$ has a minimum then we would have the second side as well,

$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \leqslant D^+f(c') \leqslant v$$

Since we can't be sure that there are both maxima and minima in the open interval, another argument is needed to simultaneously obtain both sides of the inequality chain.  For example if there is only a maximum point we have $\phi(y) > 0$ for $x < y < x+h$ and it follows that

$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} < \frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y-x} $$

I will leave the remainder of the argument to you.

Comment: Great explanation!! I'm justifying some points in the proof of the first inequality and I have not been able to justify only one: "$\displaystyle D^{+}\phi(y) = D^{+}f(y) - \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$". Could you explain it a little more?

Comment: Thanks.  We are taking the Dini derivative of a sum of two functions of $y$. The first is $f(y) - f(x)$ with derivative $D^+f(y)$ since the term $f(x)$ acts as a constant.  The second is $-\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}(y-x)$  which is actually differentiable (of the form $Ay+B$) so its Dini derivative is  the ordinary derivative which is $A = -\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$.  Now the Dini derivative of the sum is the sum of the Dini derivatives when one of the functions is actually differentiable.  This is also discussed in the book by Boas.

Comment: $D^+(f+g) = D^+f + g'$ when $g$ is differentiable.. See Boas Ch.2 Sec. 21.

Comment: This is an interesting question.  Where is it from?  Very few books go into any detail about Dini derivatives other than in proving that a monotone function is a.e. differentiable. Hence, Boas is a very useful book for this many other topics.

Comment: I got it! I'm studying Measure Theory in the master's degree. This question is from a list of preparatory exercises for the first exam. I'm using some of the recommended books I've found, and I have not found this question them in any of them... they speak very little about it, as you have quoted. I will check the reference! Thank you!

Comment: This question does not come up in Boas either -- it just has more details about Dini derivatives.